# different txt file words into a graph( with JUNG lib)

Tags: java, graph, jung

i am trying to make a graph tha reads a txt file and put the words in a graph, but it can't repeat(in case that having two same words in the file)

here is my code (USING JUNG API)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = null;
/*i have a class named 'Palavra' that returns me a string(did that cause // i'll use the class to implement some things at the word) */

        Stack<Palavra> palavras = new Stack<Palavra>(); // pilha para delimitar
                                                        // tamanho do grafo

        // Read txt
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Auryon.AURYON-PC\\Desktop\\Aula1\\teste.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*int i = 0;*/
        Graph<Palavra, Relacao> g = new SparseMultigraph<Palavra, Relacao>();
```

//The last class that i've created(will be my word relationship verification)

```
        Relacao tipo_palavra = new Relacao("connect");
```

# HERE IS THE PROBLEM

```
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.next();
            Palavra word = new Palavra(s);
            if (palavras.contains(word)) {
                s = scan.next();
            } else {
                palavras.push(word);
                g.addVertex(word);
            }
            /*
             * if (i > 0) { g.addEdge(tipo_palavra,word,palavras.lastElement());
             * //multiple edges }
                 */
            }

            System.out.println(g);


    System.out.println(palavras.size());

        }
    }
```

> > > MY NEW UPDATE

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = null;

        Stack<Palavra> palavras = new Stack<Palavra>(); // Graph Size Stack


        // Read txt
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Auryon.AURYON-PC\\Desktop\\Aula1\\teste.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        Graph<Palavra, Relacao> g = new SparseMultigraph<Palavra, Relacao>();

        Relacao tipo_palavra = new Relacao("connect");

        String s = scan.next();
        Palavra word = new Palavra(s);
        palavras.push(word);
        g.addVertex(word);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            s = scan.next();
            word = new Palavra(s);
            //THE REAL PROBLEM
            g.addVertex(word);
            g.addEdge(tipo_palavra, word, palavras.lastElement()); 
            palavras.push(word);



        }
        System.out.println(g);
        System.out.println(palavras.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it can't repeat(in case that having two same words in the file)"? Do you mean that you can't have the same two words in the Graph, meaning that each word in the graph is unique?

Comment: well, i am just trying to make a graph that connect thoose words on txt file, but i was taking problems with adding an edge because appears a message saying that i can't repeat the  same edge endpoints, so i thought that i should filter my Graph vertices, did i made myself clearly enough?

Comment: i just posted an update on post, (i don't know if i did that using the bests StackOverflows ways but, is there), i am working now in the project and glad if you could help... i will post updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer, and also my graphs work complete:

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.TreeLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.PolarPoint;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;

public class Main {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * 
     */

    // BEGIN DEEP SEARCH

    Stack<Word> pilha;

    public void buscaProfundidade(Graph<Word, Relacao> g1, Word n0) {
        HashMap<Integer, Word> visitados = new HashMap<Integer, Word>();
        pilha = new Stack<Word>();
        pilha.add(n0);
        while (!pilha.isEmpty()) {
            Word n = pilha.pop();
            marcarVisitado(n, visitados);
            processarNo(n); // print
            Collection<Word> adjacencias = g1.getNeighbors(n); // coleção dos
                                                                // adjacentes do nó
                                                                // atual
            for (Word adjacente : adjacencias) {
                if (!foiVisitado(adjacente, visitados)) {
                    pilha.push(adjacente);
                }
            }
        }
        // RENDERIZA GRAFO
        Layout<Word, Relacao> layout = new CircleLayout<Word, Relacao>(g1);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); // sets the initial size of the
                                                    // space
        // The BasicVisualizationServer<V,E> is parameterized by the edge types
        BasicVisualizationServer<Word, Relacao> vv = new BasicVisualizationServer<Word, Relacao>(layout);

        vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); // Sets the viewing area
                                                        // size
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        vv.getRenderContext().setLabelOffset(20);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("WORD INDICATOR");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void processarNo(Word n) {
        System.out.println(n);

    }

    boolean foiVisitado(Word adjacente, HashMap<Integer, Word> visitados) {

        return visitados.containsKey(adjacente.getId());

    }

    private void marcarVisitado(Word n, HashMap<Integer, Word> visitados) {
        visitados.put(n.getId(), n);

    }

    // DEEP SEARCH END
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = null;

        Stack<Word> words = new Stack<Word>();
        // CRIA GRAFO
        // Read txt

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\Auryon.AURYON-PC\\Documents\\GitHub\\java-works\\Graphs_JUNG\\teste.txt"));

            // scan = new Scanner(new
            // File("C:\\Users\\Auryon.AURYON-PC\\Desktop\\flatWiki.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Graph<Word, Relacao> g = new SparseMultigraph<Word, Relacao>();
        int i = 1;
        Relacao word_type = new Relacao("connect");
        String s = scan.next();
        Word word = new Word(i, s, s, s, s);
        words.push(word);
        g.addVertex(word);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            i++;
            s = scan.next(); // TODO:implementar classes separadas
            /*
             * s2 s3 s4
             */
            word = new Word(i, s, s, s, s);
            g.addVertex(word);
            try {
                word_type = new Relacao("");
                g.addEdge(word_type, words.lastElement(), word, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
                words.push(word);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            ;

            System.out.println(g);
            System.out.println(words.size());
        }

        Main busca = new Main();
        Collection<Word> vertices = g.getVertices();
        Word p = vertices.iterator().next(); // parametro busca
        busca.buscaProfundidade(g, p);

        // TERMINA GRAFO

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DivDiff said, it's not entirely clear what your problem is, but it sounds like you're expecting that the number of words in the input file will be the same as the number of vertices in the graph you've created (in which vertices are words).

The short version is: that will be true as long as the words in the file each only appear once.  If `word` is not already in the graph and you do this:

```
boolean result1 = g.addVertex(word);
boolean result2 = g.addVertex(word);
```

then `result1` will be `true` (graph was modified) and `result2` will be `false` (graph was not modified), as specified in the documentation for [addVertex](http://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Hypergraph.html#addVertex-V-).

This constraint--that vertices must be unique--allows the vertices to be used as keys to the internal data structures of the Graph, and more importantly as arguments to methods like getNeighbors().

UPDATE: your comment below indicates that the actual problem you're seeing is that you're trying to add the same edge with different endpoints.

In particular, you have a single edge object (`tipo_palavra`) and you're repeatedly adding that edge to the graph with different endpoints.  This will not work: each edge object must be unique.

If the edge itself doesn't have any meaning to you other than as a means of connecting two vertices, then you have two major options:

(1) Generate a new edge object for each pair of endpoints, for example, have the edge be an Integer and just increment it every time:

```
g.addEdge(i++, word1, word2);
```

(2) Use a different library to represent your graph that doesn't require that you have explicit edge objects, e.g., [Guava's common.graph library](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava/src/com/google/common/graph) (available in v20 RC1), specifically, the Graph type.

Comment: as i said to @DivDiff , i am just trying to make a graph that connect those words on txt file, but i was taking problems with adding an edge because appears a messge error saying  _italic_**edge connect already exists in this graph with endpoints** , i thought that i should filter my graph with only different words in txt file, maybe i need more theory, if you guys could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: i just have posted an update in the post, showing better the problem. I am really need a hand here, glad if you could help.

Comment: @Aury0n: I updated the answer to reflect the error you referenced.  That said: I took another look at what your code is actually doing and you're not really building a graph at all, as far as I can tell.  Again, I can't see your input, but you're reading in words, and connecting each word to the previous word.  That's not really so much a graph as it is a linked list.

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Joshua, sorry , i think i need more theory about graphs, in this step of my project, i am just trying to make a graph that connect the file words. The all project is a word Indicator, the result will be a word that exists in the txt file that  the user will input and show all the words that proceed it in the file(the real file is a txt with 285mb). I saw what you wrote above and i was thinkng about how i should connect the words in the graph(the edge object((tipo_palavra)) is a class that later will give me the words morfolgy(if is a verb, pronoun, adjective).

Comment: i will order the user search using this morfology criterial... i wrote an algorithm using the Java Web Driver api that give me the word morfology, but i can't integrate without solving my graph building.

Comment: @Aury0n well, until you figure out what you want to do (and can specify a bit better what your input data looks like and what you want the graph to look like), it's going to be difficult to help you.  :)

Comment: i will try to explain better(sorry about my english). The problem is to make a graph with the txt input file

Comment: i think the better way to do that is to stack all the words and making an g.addedge() one by one, at the same time with the scanning proccess.  that's the explanation for the line _g.addEdge(word_type,word,words.firstElement());_ . You said that this might be not the right way to do, so here is my ask, how can i do that?

Comment: i've changed the variables names to english(better to understand), after a little bit more updates, i will post here.

Comment: Don't worry about the variable names; I speak enough Spanish that a few Portuguese words aren't going to throw me.  :)  I had two points about the graph structure: (1) you can't use word_type for more than one edge with a JUNG graph, as edge objects must be unique; (2) it's not clear that there's actually a need for a graph structure if each edge you add is just connecting the current word with a previous word.

Comment: haha nice Portuguese explanation, i understand your point and agreed with you. this is an academic project and my teacher is teaching us using JUNG API. I think i need to change my methods of add an edge... but i will post an update and keep you informed(if you want)...tks again :)

Comment: Sounds good.  Please let your teacher know that if she would like to discuss what she's doing with JUNG and how she's using it for teaching, I'd be happy to contact her.  Boa sorte!  :)